# Not able to fetch particular user document by user id in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve a particular user document by its id from the collection users. When I directly pass the particular user id, I get the data. But when I pass it using variable it shows null.

My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import '../services/crud.dart';

class test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();

}
class _testState extends State<test> {

  String userID="";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ///get current user and assign his id
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() {
        userID = user.uid;
        print(userID);
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userID).snapshots(),
                  builder: (context,snapshot){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                    else return Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(snapshot.data["name"]),
                          Text(snapshot.data["email"]),
                          Text(snapshot.data["phone"].toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm using the following line of code with specifying uid it shows the result :

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('d6DshRomJMkIe9mAARAi').snapshots(),
```

But it does not work when I pass **userID** inside the document(). Even though userID contains the actual id of the logged-in user.

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userID).snapshots(),
```

The error says :

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling []("name")
```

[This is the structure of my database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko8ce.png)

[This is the error that I get on my app screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKizs.png)

Comment: Hey Peter, I have just added the screenshot of the database.

Comment: Make a little test. Initialize the userID with some id, like this: `String userID = 'd6DshRomJMkIe9mAARAi'` and check if it works with userID.

Comment: The problem remains the same even after initializing it with some id.

Comment: I asked for this little test for same reason of the @Peter answer right bellow. The query it's been executed before you get the userID. But if not works even initializing it, this is pretty weird.

Comment: Thanks for answering though :) @JRamos29. I've updated my code with Peter'sanswer even though it's not working but it starting working when I give a default id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `userID` is doesn't work because `currentUser()` is asynchronous and the `StreamBuilder` is being called even before getting the `userId` therefore try the following:

```
   Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData()async*{
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     yield* Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
```

Create a method that returns a `Stream` and then inside the `StreamBuilder` do the following:

```
children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
                  stream: getData(),
                  builder: (context,snapshot){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                    else if(snapshot.hasData){
                    return Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(snapshot.data["name"]),
                          Text(snapshot.data["email"]),
                          Text(snapshot.data["phone"].toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                   },
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                )
        ],
```

Comment: The problem remained the same while using getData() function also. When I directly pass the uid as "d6DshRomJMkIe9mAARAi" it starts showing the result.

Comment: Inside the method can you print(user.uid)

Comment: Yes, it is printing the user id properly.

Comment: the edit in my code, add  return CircularProgressIndicator(); and add   else if(snapshot.hasData){

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter  Haddad. Actually the problem was that the uid was not matching with the auth uid. Which I corrected in my signup code. The code that you gave was much cleaner than I was using. Thank you once again :)

Comment: For sure Peter, Thankyou once again.